# expected primary expression error before '>='

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am currently making a Rock, Paper, Scissors code in c++. However, when I try to compare the player guess to the computer guess I get the error in the title and more. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

void
RocPaprSkisors ()
{

  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1, 4);
  std::cout << dist(mt) << "\n";

  int player_guess;
  std::cout << "Hello! Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!" << std::endl;
  std::cout <<
    "You have to try and beat the computer by choosing either rock, paper, or scissors"
    << std::endl;
  std::cout <<
    "Rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, and paper beats rock." <<
    std::endl;
  std::cout << "Please guess 1 for paper, 2 for rock, or 3 for scissors" <<
    std::endl;
  std::cin >> player_guess;
  if (player_guess == dist(mt))
    {
      std::cout << "You tied!" << std::endl;
      std::cout << dist(mt) << std::endl;
    }
  else
    {
      if (player_guess == 1 and dist(mt) < 3 and >= 2)
    {
      std::cout << "The computer guessed rock! That means you win!" <<
        std::endl;
    }
      else
    {
      if (player_guess == 2 and dist(mt) >= 1 and < 2)
        {
          std::cout <<
        "The computer guessed paper. That means you be loser. :(" <<
        std::endl;
        }
      else
        {
          if (player_guess == 1 and dist(mt) >= 3 and <= 4)
        {
          std::cout <<
            "The computer guessed scissors. That means you be loser. :("
            << std::endl;
        }
          else
        {
          if (player_guess == 3 and dist(mt) >= 1 and < 2)
            {
              std::cout <<
            "The computer guessed paper!. That means you win!" <<
            std::endl;
            }
          else
            {
              if (player_guess == 2 and dist(mt) >= 3 and <= 4)
            {
              std::cout <<
                "The computer guessed scissors! That means you win!"
                << std::endl;
            }
              else
            {
              if (player_guess == 3 and dist(mt) >= 2 and < 3)
                {
                  std::cout <<
                "The computer guessed rock. That means you be   loser. :("
                << std::endl;
                            {
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  RocPaprSkisors ();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the code I get these errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void RocPaprSkisors()':
main.cpp:39:50: error: expected primary-expression before '>=' token
       if (player_guess == 1 and dist(mt) < 3 and >= 2)
                                                  ^
main.cpp:46:48: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
    if (player_guess == 2 and dist(mt) >= 1 and < 2)
                                                ^
main.cpp:54:52: error: expected primary-expression before '<=' token
        if (player_guess == 1 and dist(mt) >= 3 and <= 4)
                                                    ^
main.cpp:62:49: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
     if (player_guess == 3 and dist(mt) >= 1 and < 2)
                                                 ^
main.cpp:70:53: error: expected primary-expression before '<=' token
         if (player_guess == 2 and dist(mt) >= 3 and <= 4)
                                                     ^
main.cpp:78:50: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
      if (player_guess == 3 and dist(mt) >= 2 and < 3)
                                                  ^
```

Does anyone know how to fix these errors? I just started coding in c++ so please keep your answers simple please.

Comment: The compiler is complaining that `>= 2` isn't anything that can be evaluated as is. What is supposed to be `>= 2`? You probably meant to write `dist(mt) >= 2`.

Comment: a) Readup on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve b) replace `and` with `&&` c) replace `dist(mt) < 3 and >= 2` with `dist(mt) < 3 && dist(mt) >= 2`.

Comment: @UKMonkey but `and` is `&&`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann fair shout... though when people post code looking like it does on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative and wonder why they don't get help, not one tear will be shed!

Comment: @UKMonkey absolutely. Yet it is interesting, which is why I added the comment.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann first of all using `and` or `&&` is a personal preference, second your statement can make it syntactically correct, but logically is wrong

Comment: Make yourself a favor and go to read a C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code:

if you have requirement, which can be written mathematically `1 < a < 5` you cannot express it like:

```
if( a > 1 and < 5 )
```

it must be:

```
if( a > 1 and a < 5 )
```

as this is programming language, not one to write mathematical equations. That issue leads to syntax errors.

Now you have logical error in your program - you cannot call `dist()` every time as it generates new random value on every call. What you need is call it once, remember that in a variable and use that in following logic. And you probably do not need random value of type `double` generated in the first place, as you need integer in [1,3] range

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do I store the number in a separate variable so that it does not generate a new one?

Comment: @Need_help `std::uniform_real_distribution<int> dist(1, 4); int comp_guess = dist(mt);` and use that as you use `player_guess`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know what to evalutate `>= 2` to, becuase you have not stated it (your syntax is incorrect).

What you probably mean to do is:

```
if (player_guess == 1 && dist(mt) < 3 && dist(m) >= 2)
```

and

```
if (player_guess == 2 && dist(mt) >= 1 && dist(m) < 2)
```

etc.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: If I write `if( rand() < 3 and rand() >= 2 )` would you call it correct answer?